Why does the register value reset in my assembly program
AREA MyCode, CODE, READONLY
ENTRY

CHECK_DIGIT    EQU 11       ; Position of the check digit in UPC code
VALID   EQU 1               ; Reps a valid UPC result
INVALID EQU 2               ; Reps an invalid UPC result

LDR r5, =UPC                ; Loads the address of UPC into r0

UPC DCB "013800150738"      ; correct UPC string
MOV r1, #0                  ; First sum for odd index numbers
MOV r2, #0                  ; Second sum for even index numbers
MOV r3, #0                  ; Index counter to iterate through the UPC code addresses

Loop
LDRB r4, \[r5, r3\]         ; Load single byte from UPC string
SUB r4, r4, #'0'            ; Convert ASCII to integer

TST r3, #1                  ; Check if index is odd/even
ADDNE r1, r1, r4            ; If index is odd, add to odd sum
ADDEQ r2, r2, r4            ; If index is even, add to even sum

ADD r3, r3, #1              ; Increment index
CMP r3, #CHECK_DIGIT        ; Check if check digit has been reached
BNE Loop                    ; Repeat if not

ADD r2, r2, r2, LSL #1      ; Multiply second sum (even indices) by 3
ADD r1, r1, r2              ; Add first (odd indices) sum

LDRB r4, [r5, #CHECK_DIGIT] ; Load check digit
SUB r4, r4, #'0'            ; Convert the check digit from ASCII
ADD r1, r1, r4              ; Add the check digit to the total sum
MOV r0, #INVALID

TenCheck
SUBS r1, r1, #10            ; Subtract 10 from r1
BGT TenCheck                ; Repeat until r1 \< 10
CMP r1, #0                  ; compare to see if r1 is 0

MOV r0, #VALID
END

everything is right until the last line executes and r0 has 0 instead of 1 or 2 (depending on if the upc code is valid or noT)
Ive been debugging for a while in Keil, cant figure out why its resetting the r0 register to 0.

For starters, do not put your UPC which is data into the execution path. While r0 should not be zero, you seem to be missing something as your code sets it to #VALID unconditionally.
